# ggplot2: No legend with multiple geom_point

Tags: r

I have a plot with several single geom_point-plots and I would like to specify the shape and color for each plot individually.

Somehow I am really struggling with getting a proper legend and also I could not find a solution on stackoverflow.
I tried to use "fill" in the aes-command, but if I have more than two plots with fill, I get the error:

> "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (1): x, y"

This is a simplified minimal example of the basic structure of my plot:

```
da <- as.character(c(1:10))
type <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a" )
value <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(da, type, value)

require("ggplot2")
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = subset(df, type %in% c("a")), aes(x=da, y=value), shape=1, color="red",  size=5) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, type %in% c("b")), aes(x=da, y=value), shape=2, color="darkorange", size=3) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, type %in% c("c")), aes(x=da, y=value), shape=3, color="violet", size=3)
```

How can I add a legend with custom labels?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you create separate layers and manually create a legend when you can simply create one layer and map aesthetics to your data (in this case, simply `"type"`)? If you want specific colour or shape values, you can specify these using scales such as `scale_colour_manual`, `scale_shape_discrete`, etc)

```r
da <- as.character(c(1:10))
type <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a" )
value <- c(1:10)
df <- data.frame(da, type, value)

require("ggplot2")
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
ggplot(df, aes(x=da, y=value, color=type, shape = type, size = type)) + 
  geom_point()
#> Warning: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>